# Can watchOS notification show Custom embedded fonts

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, watchos-3

In watchOS, if a custom font is embedded in the app, that font works definitely on `WkInterfaceLabel`, `WKInterfaceButton`, etc... .

Does that font works on watchOS's notification views ?

If not, is there any possible way like we can install font profile on our iOS device and can we use custom font for notification view ?

Comment: Please look at my answer below. It may help you...

Answer (score 1):

Custom fonts are genuinely not supported anywhere except your main `WatchKit` app.

Below are text form [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TextandLabels.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH19-SW4) :

**Using Custom Fonts :**

> By default, the Watch app interface, **glance interfaces**, and
>   **notification interfaces** use the system font for displaying text. Your
>   Watch app interface may also use custom fonts (glances and
>   notifications can only use the system font). To use custom fonts, you
>   must install the fonts into both the Watch app bundle and the WatchKit
>   extension bundle, as shown below:

Hope this helps you !!!